# I published a review article in a journal that is not well known. Can I include it in my CV?

Tags: cv, review-articles

A few months ago I published a review in this [journal](http://ithaca.unisalento.it/) . Given that the journal is in Italian (although the review is available in both Italian and English) and that it is handled by a local university, I am not sure I could include this publication in my CV. What do you think?

Comment: Why wouldn’t you?

Comment: Not only _can_ you include it, you _must_ include it.

Comment: @JeffE, why "must"? Anyone can choose to leave out whatever they want from their CV.

Comment: @JeffE, "should" maybe, but not "must".

Comment: At least in my corner of academia, a CV is supposed to include a compete list of publications. Omitting a publication violates the first rule of CVs: **Do not lie.**

Comment: @JeffE, I have never heard such a rule. I have always created (and recommend people to create) CVs selectively. You present whatever you want, as long as it is true. It is a lie to falsify something that you did not publish, but it is not a lie to choose not to show something that you don't want to. Unless someone explicitly insists that you publish everything without omitting anything (which I have never encountered in any professional context), there is no lie to selectively omit whatever you think might be less relevant.

Comment: Some CVs have a section called "Selected Publications".

Answer (score 8):

A publication is work that you have published. You may include anything you want. The fact that many readers of your CV might not recognize the journal is irrelevant. Even for English-language journals, many readers might not recognize some journals.

If your CV is targeted to English readers, if your review were only in Italian, then it would be a good idea to include both the original Italian title an English translation. But if, as your question seems to indicate, the original article is available both in Italian and in English, then for an English CV, you should probably list only the English title.